# Can $\sum_{d=D}^{D+x} d^a {d \choose L}$ be simplified to closed form?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{d=D}^{D+x} d^a {d \choose L}$$

Where $a, L, D, x$ are known positive integers. Can this be reduced to a closed form?

Edit: I want to compute the above summation in time complexity way less than $O(x)$

Comment: Yes, the summand is a polynomial in d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponential generating function of this with respect to $a$ is

$$\eqalign{ g(z) &= \sum_{a=0}^\infty \sum_{d=D}^{D+x} \frac{(zd)^a}{a!} {d \choose L}\cr
&= \sum_{d=D}^{D+x} e^{zd} {d \choose L} \cr
&= e^{z(D+x+1)} {{D+x+1}\choose L} {}_2F_1(1,D+x+2;D+x+2-L; e^z) 
 - e^{zD} {D \choose L} {}_2F_1(1,D+1;D+1-L; e^z) }$$
(according to Maple)

EDIT: For fixed $a$ and $L$, $d^a {d \choose L}$ is a certain polynomial of degree $L+a$ in $d$, say $p(d)$, and then $P(m) = \sum_{d=0}^m p(d)$ is a polynomial of degree $L+a+1$ in $m$ (see [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)).  Once you have $P(m)$, computing your sum $P(D+x) - P(D-1)$ is $O(1)$ (in a model of computation where all additions and multiplications are $O(1)$).

Comment: I'm sorry i should re frame my question. I was looking to compute the summation in $O(1)$ time or atleast in time way less than $O(x)$.

Comment: Can hypergeometric function be computed so fast?